# How can std::vector be converted to std::span?

Tags: c++, c++20

In the docs on [std::span constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/span), there isn't one that accepts an std::vector.

Then, how come this code ([source page](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-20-std-span)) compiles?

```
// createSpan.cpp

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <span>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;

    std::vector myVec{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    
    std::span mySpan1{myVec};                                        // (1)
    std::span mySpan2{myVec.data(), myVec.size()};                   // (2)
    
    bool spansEqual = std::equal(mySpan1.begin(), mySpan1.end(),
                                 mySpan2.begin(), mySpan2.end());
    
    std::cout << "mySpan1 == mySpan2: " << spansEqual << std::endl;  // (3)

    std::cout << std::endl;
    
}
```

i.e. which constructor of std::span was invoked at (1)?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's constructor (7) in the overload set:

```
template< class R >
explicit(extent != std::dynamic_extent)
constexpr span( R&& r );
```

From the explanation:

> Constructs a span that is a view over the range r; the resulting span has `size() == std::ranges::size(r)` and `data() == std::ranges::data(r)`.

There are further restriction on when this signature takes part in overload resolution, but that's the essence. And `std::vector` satisfies these requirements.

It's a good thing that this is kept only as constrained as necessary, because it allows custom (non-`std`) containers to allow for implicit conversion to `std::span` instances.

Comment: And when you only want a view on a part of the vector? `auto s = std::span<double>(v.data()+start, 5)`?

Comment: `std::span{v}.subspan(start, 5)`