# Is using std::span into an std::vector after push_back is called undefined behavior

Tags: c++, vector, undefined-behavior, ownership-semantics, std-span

My understanding of `std::span` is that it is essentially contains pointer into a container, a size, and some useful member functions.

```
template<typename T>
class SimpleSpan {
    T* ptr;
    size_t length;
    // some member functions
}
```

I can take a span of a vector as seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64900594/how-can-stdvector-be-converted-to-stdspan).

If I add entries to the end of a vector, the vector may need to be resized. When the vector is resized, the following steps occur (order not important).

1. A new array is allocated on the heap with more space.
2. The entries from the vector are moved to the new array.
3. The member `ptr` of the `vector` to the `vector`'s array is changed to the start of the new array.
4. The old array is deallocated.

Does anything happen to a `span` if the `vector`'s array needs to be reallocated and made larger?  Is using a `span` into a `vector` after `push_back` is called on the `vector` undefined behavior?

Comment: `push_back` *might* invalidate pointers, references and iterators to its elements. This only happens if `push_back` had to increase the `capacity`. If `capacity() > size()` before `push_back` then the span will remain valid.

Comment: resize is not necessarily reallocate, only when capacity is not sufficient, though its only a nitpick on wording

Answer (score 3):

> My understanding of std::span is that it is essentially contains pointer into a container, a size, and some useful member functions.

That's not *quite* correct. `std::span` completely ignores where the data lives. It handles just the data itself. The nature (and even notion) of the data belonging to a container is completely erased away. All it cares about is that the data is contiguous in memory.

So if a vector ever resizes, which can happen during a `push_back()`. It's possible that the data is moved to a different memory location, invalidating any pointers pointing to it. This in turn, invalidates any `std::span` referring to that data.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation on [`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) reads:

> If the new size() is greater than capacity() then all iterators and references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated. Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated.

There is your answer right there: **If** the vector had to be resized, your access through an old span would be invalid. If it hadn't, it wouldn't.