# Conversion of std::vector to std::span<T>

Tags: c++, c++20, ctad

I'd like to generalize my code to take `std::span` rather than `std::vector` as parameter, but without losing the convenience of the auto-conversion you get when passing in a `std::vector` (see [How can std::vector be converted to std::span?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64900594)).

However, the functions in question are templated on the element type -- and I get a compile fail on `use_span_t`, below.

```
void use_span(std::span<const double>) {}

template <typename T>
void use_span_t(std::span<const T>)
{
}

const std::vector<double> v{1, 2, 3};
use_span(v); // ok
use_span_t(v); // candidate template ignored: could not match 'span' against 'vector' (clang16)
use_span_t<double>(v); // ok
```

What am I doing wrong, and is there a workaround which doesn't involve explicit types at the callsite (`use_span_t<double>`), or something like the following at the called site.

```
template <typename T>
void use_span_t(const std::vector<T>& v)
{
    use_span_t(v);
}
```

Comment: The problem with templates is that template deduction is performed first,and parameter conversions later. So the compiler looks at the template, and asks itself "What type T turns a vector into a span? Don't know - try another function". In `use_span_t<double>` you tell it what T should be, and then it can work out the rest.

Comment: @BoP when template deduction is done implicit conversions are forbidden to prevent unexpected bugs or ambiguity. So there is no "later".

Comment: @Marek - There is a later if you find several functions and have to do an overload resolution. Then conversions are possible at that stage. It is not uncommon to expect conversions be done first (as we humans can easily see them), and then do the template deduction. I wanted to say that this is not what happens.

Comment: Thanks both. I just found a great blog post that gives an overview at https://preshing.com/20210315/how-cpp-resolves-a-function-call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function template is basically useless:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void use_span_t(std::span<const T>);
```

Because not only does it not accept a `vector<double>` or `vector<double> const` as you've seen, it doesn't even accept a `span<double>`. It accepts, precisely, a `span<double const>`. Which is highly limited. It'd be very nice if there were a way for this to work, but...

Until then, if what you want to do is deduce `T` for any contiguous range and get a span over `T const` over that, you'll have to do it this way:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void f(std::span<const T>);

template <std::ranges::contiguous_range R>
    requires std::ranges::sized_range<R>
void f(R&& r) {
    f(std::span<const std::ranges::range_value_t<R>>(r));
}
```

Any `contiguous` + `sized` is convertible to `span`, we just have to do it explicitly. `range_value_t<R>` gives us the value type (which is `double` for both `vector<double>` and `const vector<double>`), so we can use that to construct the correct `span`.

If we called `f` with a `span<T const>` already, the first overload would be chosen. Anything else, including `span<T>` (for non-`const` `T`), would pick the second which would then forward to the first.

I also wrote a post about [coercing deep const-ness](https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2021/09/10/deep-const/) almost exactly two years ago now.

Comment: That's interesting  thank you -- hadn't seen the concepts defined outside of <concepts>. I could use your approach. However, I had been wondering if I should discard `span` altogether and write my function directly in terms of a container template parameter. With this approach I could have a template parameter for the container, and maybe also constrain the element type of the container to be `T`,, if the function is in a `class<T>`. Otherwise I can get the element type from the range.

Comment: @TooTone Using `span` is very nice: it's very clear from the function signature that you're not mutating, and you know exactly what interface you're dealing with, and you have fewer template instantiations. You can't get that otherwise.

Comment: "*Any `contiguous_range` is convertible to `span`*" This is true in the vast majority of cases, and it's worth noting that this is not the case for outliers that don't model `sized_range`.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Gah, oops!

Comment: I'm using your solution and it's working well :). Just to check, we don't need `std::forward` on `r` in `f(std::span<const std::ranges::range_value_t<R>>(r));`?

Comment: @TooTone You do not. While typically forwarding references are used to, well, forward, in ranges code forwarding references are simply used to allow lvalues or rvalues in a way that preserves constness (because `T const&` allows either but forces const, while `T&` only allows lvalues). `span` is non-owning, there's no reason to forward.

Comment: Appreciate all the help & advice.